# Mongo aggregate query with forEach function in pymongo not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have the following mongo aggregate query

```
db.configurations.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{model:"$model", vendor :"$vendor",access_level : "$access_level",config_data_type :"$config_data_type"}, dups:{$push:"$_id"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.dups.shift();
  db.configurations.remove({_id : {$in: doc.dups}});
});
```

For pymongo i have written a equivalent of it as:

```
pipeline = [{"$group":{"_id":{"model":"$model", "vendor" :"$vendor","access_level" : "$access_level","config_data_type" :"$config_data_type"}, "dups":{"$push":"$_id"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},{"$match":{"count": {"$gt": 1}}}]

dest_col.aggregate(pipeline).forEach(bson.Code( '''
function(doc){
  doc.dups.shift();
  dest_col.remove({"_id ": {"$in": doc.dups}});
}'''));
```

It is resulting in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'CommandCursor' object has no attribute 'forEach'
```

Please correct if any syntax error i have done. or let me know if any other format i need to follow to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the aggregate inside `list` like below - Because aggregate function returns a `cursor` object. Also previous solution was not working because pythin don't have anything like `forEach`. You will have to do `for in` to iterate.

```
result = list(dest_col.aggregate(pipeline))

for doc in result:
  bson.Code( '''
function(doc){
  doc.dups.shift();
  dest_col.remove({"_id ": {"$in": doc.dups}});
}''')

I am not python developer. Plz chk the code for syntax errors.
```

Comment: I get this error -> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'forEach'

Comment: Thanks for upvoting.Can you accept the answer if it worked for you.